# Terraform module for GCP firestore document

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, terraform

I am trying to generate terraform module for GCP firestore document db.

```
resource "google_firestore_document" "mydoc" {
    project     = "my-project-name"
    collection  = "somenewcollection"
    document_id = "my-doc-%{random_suffix}"
    fields      = "{\"akey\":{\"stringValue\":\"avalue\"},\"createdBy\":{\"stringValue\":\"xyz\"}}"
    }
```

I need to build the fields dynamically from a variable list.

```
   variable "field" {
        description = "Field names. Provide minimum two fields"
        default = [
        {"fname" : "name",
        "ftype": "stringValue",
         "fvalue": "xyz"}
         ]   
         }
```

I tired to build using dynamic block but no luck.

if anyone has any idea then please help me with this request

Comment: Did you receive an error? If yes, please include in your question.

Comment: Hi John.. thanks for the response.. actually i was not able to build. there was no error